# React, different env files with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to set up different environment files in a React project (using create-react-app). I following the [official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) but I am getting an error:

> '.env.development' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I have `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.development`, `.env.production` in the same level as `package.json` and `src/`

My scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Also tried other option: `"start": ".env.local, .env.development, .env"`.

Both return similar errors as referenced above when I run `npm start`.

All my keys start with the prefix: REACT_APP_. Ex: `REACT_APP_API_KEY`.

What am I missing?

Comment: This medium article might be worth for you to look at: 
https://dev.to/rajeshroyal/handle-multiple-environments-in-reactjs-dev-stag-prod-1b9e

Answer (score 3):

Here are the env files you can use and their priority (available with `react-scripts@1.0.0` and higher):

> `.env`: Default.

> `.env.local`: Local overrides. This file is loaded for all environments except test.

> `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.production`: Environment-specific settings.

> `.env.development.local`, `.env.test.local`, `.env.production.local`: Local overrides of environment-specific settings.

Which means an environment variable for `production` goes in `.env.production` file, etc. And here are the steps to follow:

1. Create your `.env`, or `.env.production` file... in the root directory of the project, same folder as where `package.json` is.
2. You define your environment variable with the prefix `REACT_APP_` within those env files, like so:

> REACT_APP_API_KEY=343535345235452452

3. And you use them in your code this way :

> - In a JavaScript file:
>
> ```
> process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
> ```
>
> - In an HTML file:
>
> ```
> <title>%REACT_APP_API_KEY%</title>
> ```

Though if you wanna set an environment variable within the `scripts`, you could do it like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_API_KEY=343535345235452452 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the **env-cmd** package to use multiple env. Which is the best way to handle it.
Just follow this doc for more info [Multiple env example for react](https://betterprogramming.pub/managing-environments-for-provisional-builds-with-react-app-1fb411e3597) and [env-Cmd package details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)

Also, please check which **react/react-scripts** version you are using in your project and check the version of **react/react-scripts** that you have created for a demo which working fine for you.